# rolling return for all groups

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset, where the values represent returns.

```
date        SP500       MEUR        
1/3/1973     0.0049      0.003078    
1/4/1973    -0.001194    0.003365    
1/5/1973     0.004882    0.004439   
1/8/1973    -0.000198    0.000196   
1/9/1973     0          -0.000295   
1/10/1973   -0.001983    0.000884       
1/11/1973    0.007949   -0.000785       
1/12/1973   -0.007394    0.003634
```

I would like to compute the 3 day, 10 day, 15 day forward return for each column above (only 2 are being shown here), each of these columns should be then added to the above table as SP500.3day SP5500.10day

Is there a way to do without doing two nested loops?  The output should look like:

```
date        SP500       MEUR        SP500_3day    MEUR_3day
1/3/1973     0.0049      0.003078    0.003483442     0.00801647
1/4/1973    -0.001194    0.003365    0.004683033     0.004339502
1/5/1973     0.004882    0.004439   -0.002180607     0.000784855
1/8/1973    -0.000198    0.000196    0.005950237    -0.000196723
1/9/1973     0          -0.000295   -0.001487759     0.003732663
1/10/1973   -0.001983    0.000884       
1/11/1973    0.007949   -0.000785       
1/12/1973   -0.007394    0.003634
```

For example,
`1/3/1973:  SP500.3day  = ((1+ -0.001194)(1+0.004882)(1+-0.000198))-1`

Comment: can you show your expected output?

Comment: added output thanks

Comment: is it log return or standard return

Comment: standard return

Comment: it is not quite the answer i was looking for but thank you for the attempt

Comment: Feel free to elaborate on what is missing.  As noted in the answer, there is really nothing slow about the for loops here.  Of course you could do some custom coding in numpy or numba that will be a little faster but also be less readable and take longer to code.  Unless you have really big data such that the suggested answer is too slow, I really doubt that would be worth it tho, but maybe that's what you want?

Answer (score 1):

There is really nothing bad (or slow) about loops here.  It is mainly iterating over rows that you want to avoid.  So the code below takes advantage of pandas vectorized operations and should be plenty fast.  Note that all values are assumed to be returns, not prices.

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'sp500':(abs(np.random.randn(12)/10)), 
                    'meur' :(abs(np.random.randn(12)/10)), }, 
                    index=pd.date_range('1-3-1973', periods=12, freq='B') )
for i in [3,10]:  
    for c in ['meur','sp500']:
        df[c+'_'+str(i)] = df[c].rolling(i).apply( lambda x: (x+1).prod() - 1 ).shift(-i)

                meur     sp500    meur_3   sp500_3   meur_10  sp500_10
1973-01-03  0.149139  0.108563  0.159387  0.301195  1.659468  1.717294
1973-01-04  0.063890  0.099735  0.330156  0.251649  1.793686  1.494265
1973-01-05  0.044398  0.028298  0.552121  0.418219       NaN       NaN
1973-01-08  0.043435  0.150629  0.636865  0.531661       NaN       NaN
1973-01-09  0.220593  0.057860  0.392830  0.509988       NaN       NaN
1973-01-10  0.218679  0.165144  0.227176  0.460029       NaN       NaN
1973-01-11  0.100405  0.242668  0.281450  0.276749       NaN       NaN
1973-01-12  0.038619  0.042891  0.349266  0.307352       NaN       NaN
1973-01-15  0.073737  0.126594  0.404363  0.171437       NaN       NaN
1973-01-16  0.149073  0.086674       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
1973-01-17  0.093583  0.067889       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
1973-01-18  0.117583  0.009471       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```